# "this" keyword in literal objects

Tags: javascript

i have the following code . i expected **console.log(this.info)** to print **john** in the browser console . but it prints undefined . can someone tell me why ?

```
const firstObj = {
    info: "john",
    display: function (logger) {
        logger();
    }
}


const secondObj = {
    info: "mike",
    logger: function () {
        console.log(this.info); // logs undefind . but i expected to log john
    }
};


firstObj.display(secondObj.logger);
```

Comment: You are calling `logger();`, not `something.logger()`. If you were calling `something.logger()` then `this` would be `something`, but there is nothing.

Comment: When you pass `secondObj.logger` to the function, you break the relationship with the object.

Comment: @Quentin thank you very much . i know how it works now .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind the object to specify the *context* in which `this` should work:

```
secondObj.logger.bind(firstObj)
```

```js
const firstObj = {
    info: "john",
    display: function (logger) {
        logger();
    }
}


const secondObj = {
    info: "mike",
    logger: function () {
        console.log(this.info); // logs undefind . but i expected to log john
    }
};


firstObj.display(secondObj.logger.bind(firstObj));
```